# Very slow mysql query: left join multiple table and where clause for each table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one base table(id table) and multiple tables(data table) which have the data related to the id's and each table has different type data.
I want to filter id's by multiple condition from these different table.

I created query as follows, but this is too slow like 3 minutes. I checked explain information but still can not find better way. Could anyone find the way to get it faster?

query

```
    select jj.id, jj.imgtitle, jj.alias
    from jjtable jj
    inner join jjtable_catg jjc on jj.catid = jjc.cid
    left join jjtable_map jjtm_name on jj.id = jjtm_name.picid
    left join jjtable_tags jjts_name on jjtm_name.tid = jjts_name.tid
    left join jjtable_map_ge jjtm_ge on jj.id = jjtm_ge.picid
    left join jjtable_tags jjts_ge on jjtm_ge.tid = jjts_ge.tid
    left join jjtable_map_ban jjtm_ban on jj.id = jjtm_ban.picid
    left join jjtable_tags jjts_ban on jjtm_ban.tid = jjts_ban.tid
    left join jjtable_map_per jjtm_per on jj.id = jjtm_per.picid
    left join jjtable_tags jjts_per on jjtm_per.tid = jjts_per.tid
    left join jjtable_map_fea jjtm_fea on jj.id = jjtm_fea.picid
    left join jjtable_tags jjts_fea on jjtm_fea.tid = jjts_fea.tid
    left join jjtable_map_ev jjtm_ev on jj.id = jjtm_ev.picid
    left join jjtable_tags jjts_ev on jjtm_ev.tid = jjts_ev.tid 
    left join jjtable_map_ag jjtm_ag on jj.id = jjtm_ag.picid
    left join jjtable_tags jjts_ag on jjtm_ag.tid = jjts_ag.tid
    left join jjtable_map_fa jjtm_fa on jj.id = jjtm_fa.picid
    left join jjtable_tags jjts_fa on jjtm_fa.tid = jjts_fa.tid
    left join jjtable_map_im jjtm_im on jj.id = jjtm_im.picid
    left join jjtable_tags jjts_im on jjtm_im.tid = jjts_im.tid where jj.published = 1
    and jj.approved  = 1 
    and jjts_fea.tid in(87,90)
    and jjts_fea.delete_flag = 0
    and jjtm_fea.delete_flag = 0
    and jjc.cid in(4,10)
    and jjts_name.tid in(77)
    and jjts_name.delete_flag = 0
    and jjtm_name.delete_flag = 0
    and jjts_per.tid in(28,36)
    and jjts_per.delete_flag = 0
    and jjtm_per.delete_flag = 0
    and jjts_ag.tid in(98,99)
    and jjts_ag.delete_flag = 0
    and jjtm_ag.delete_flag = 0
    and jjts_fa.tid in(104,107)
    and jjts_fa.delete_flag = 0
    and jjtm_fa.delete_flag = 0 
    group by jj.id 
    order by case when date(jj.date) > date_add(date(now()), interval -14 day) then jj.view end DESC, jj.id DESC
```

EDIT: Thank you for your comment. firstly I add information as your request.

WHY NEED THIS QUERY;

This query are intended to received the post data from "form input" tag which user select options from different categories to filter ID. That is why this query includes tables and data which are not used in this example.

The reason why there are so many left join is that each 'map' table has category mapping information to filter ID's. etc, user want to find ID's which are mapped with 'fea', 87, 90, and 'ag', 98, 99.

explain select;

```
        +----+-------------+--------------+--------+-------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
        | id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys     | key             | key_len | ref                                            | rows | Extra                           |
        +----+-------------+--------------+--------+-------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjts_name    | const  | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY         | 4       | const                                          |    1 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjc          | range  | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY         | 4       | NULL                                           |    2 | Using where                     |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjts_pe      | range  | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY         | 4       | NULL                                           |    2 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjts_fea     | range  | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY         | 4       | NULL                                           |    2 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjts_ag      | range  | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY         | 4       | NULL                                           |    2 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjts_fa      | range  | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY         | 4       | NULL                                           |    2 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jj           | ref    | PRIMARY,idx_catid | idx_catid       | 4       | jjc.cid                                        |   95 | Using where                     |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjtm_ag      | eq_ref | udx_picid_tid     | udx_picid_tid   | 8       | jj.id,jjts_ag.tid                              |    1 | Using where                     |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjtm_fa      | eq_ref | udx_picid_tid     | udx_picid_tid   | 8       | jj.id,jjts_fa.tid                              |    1 | Using where                     |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjtm_fea     | eq_ref | udx_picid_tid     | udx_picid_tid   | 8       | jj.id,jjts_fea.tid                             |    1 | Using where                     |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjtm_pe      | eq_ref | udx_picid_tid     | udx_picid_tid   | 8       | jjtm_fea.picid,jjts_per.tid                    |    1 | Using where                     |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjtm_ev      | ref    | udx_picid_tid     | udx_picid_tid   | 4       | jjtm_fa.picid                                  |    3 | Using index                     |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjts_ev      | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY         | 4       | jjtm_ev.tid                                    |    1 | Using index                     |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjtm_im      | ref    | udx_picid_tid     | udx_picid_tid   | 4       | jjtm_pe.picid                                  |    6 | Using index                     |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjts_im      | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY         | 4       | jjtm_im.tid                                    |    1 | Using index                     |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjtm_ge      | ref    | udx_picid_tid     | udx_picid_tid   | 4       | jj.id                                          |   23 | Using index                     |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjts_ge      | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY         | 4       | jjtm_ge.tid                                    |    1 | Using index                     |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjtm_ban     | ref    | udx_picid_tid     | udx_picid_tid   | 4       | jjtm_pe.picid                                  |    9 | Using index                     |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjts_ban     | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY         | 4       | jjtm_ban.tid                                   |    1 | Using index                     |
        |  1 | SIMPLE      | jjtm_name    | eq_ref | udx_picid_tid     | udx_picid_tid   | 8       | jjtm_fea.picid,const                           |    1 | Using where                     |
        +----+-------------+--------------+--------+-------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
        20 rows in set (2 min 15.87 sec)
```

show columns;

```
        mysql> show columns from jjtables;
        +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
        +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | id           | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
        | catid        | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
        | imgtitle     | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | alias        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
        | date         | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | view         | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
        | published    | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
        | approved     | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
        +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


        mysql> show columns from jjtable_catg;
        +--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
        +--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | cid          | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
        | name         | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |         |                |
        | alias        | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |         |                |
        | parent       | int(11)             | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
        | desc         | text                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        | order        | int(11)             | NO   |     | 0       |                |
        +--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


        mysql> show columns from jjtable_tags;
        +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
        | Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
        +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
        | tid          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
        | name         | varchar(60) | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                |
        | talias       | varchar(60) | NO   |     |                     |                |
        | ttypeid      | int(11)     | NO   |     | 1                   |                |
        | pa_tid       | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
        | delete_flag  | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
        | created      | datetime    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
        | created_by   | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
        | modified     | datetime    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
        | modified_by  | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
        | t_due        | datetime    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
        +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+


        mysql> show columns from jjtable_map;
        +-------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
        | Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
        +-------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
        | id          | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
        | picid       | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
        | tid         | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
        | delete_flag | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
        | created     | datetime   | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
        | created_by  | int(11)    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
        | modified    | datetime   | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
        | modified_by | int(11)    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
        +-------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Sorry for my poor explanation. I hope this edit help your better understanding.
EDIT END
Regards

Comment: To optimize a query, **we need to see the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.

Comment: Basically, any column that you're joining on like `jjtm_map_per.tid` should have an index on it.

Comment: Can you explain what all those left joins are supposed to accomplish? You don't even use (i.e. aggregate) the data they generate - you even use them like *inner* joins, actually.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I add EDIT data for your request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: Convert your left joins to a bunch of `WHERE EXISTS` sub-queries and drop the `GROUP BY`, because (that's my suspicion here) that's what you really wanted to express.

```
select 
    jj.id, jj.imgtitle, jj.alias
from 
    jjtable jj
    -- you could drop this join, you don't do anything with jjtable_catg
    inner join jjtable_catg jjc on jjc.cid = jj.catid
where
    jj.published = 1
    and jj.approved  = 1 
    and jjc.cid in(4, 10)
    and exists (
      select 1 
      from jjtable_map m inner join jjtable_tags t on m.tid = t.tid 
      where m.picid = jj.id m.delete_flag = 0 and t.tid in (77) and t.delete_flag = 0
    )
    and exists (
      select 1 
      from jjtable_map_per m inner join jjtable_tags t on m.tid = t.tid 
      where m.picid = jj.id m.delete_flag = 0 and t.tid in (28,36) and t.delete_flag = 0
    )
    and exists (
      select 1 
      from jjtable_map_fea m inner join jjtable_tags t on m.tid = t.tid 
      where m.picid = jj.id m.delete_flag = 0 and t.tid in (87,90) and t.delete_flag = 0
    )
    and exists (
      select 1 
      from jjtable_map_ag m inner join jjtable_tags t on m.tid = t.tid 
      where m.picid = jj.id m.delete_flag = 0 and t.tid in (98,99) and t.delete_flag = 0
    )
    and exists (
      select 1 
      from jjtable_map_fa m inner join jjtable_tags t on m.tid = t.tid 
      where m.picid = jj.id m.delete_flag = 0 and t.tid in (104,107) and t.delete_flag = 0
    )
order by 
    case when date(jj.date) > date_add(date(now()), interval -14 day) then jj.view end DESC, 
    jj.id DESC
```

Also create these composite indexes (if they're missing):

- `jjtable_catg`: `(cid)`
- `jjtable_tags`: `(tid, delete_flag)`
- `jjtable_map` and all `jjtable_map_*`: `(picid, delete_flag, tid)`

Comment: This is exelent! This query reduce time spent from 3 minutes to 0.03 seconds! I did not even know EXIST statement. One more question; According to SHOW COLUMNS information I added, Do you think I should add INDEX on only 3 columns below. 
jjtable_tags: (delete_flag)
jjtable_map and all jjtable_map_*: (delete_flag, tid)

Comment: My point with the composite index is: If all columns that are necessary to fulfill the condition (like *"has tag id X and is not flagged as deleted"*) are in the index, the sever does not even have to look at the underlying table. It can run the entire SELECT+JOINs just by looking at pre-sorted data in the indexes. This speeds up things considerably, but requires carefully crafted indexes. The index recommendation in my answer is how I would think it's best. You can try out different index configurations and use EXPLAIN to see whether MySQL uses them and how they affect query performance.

Comment: I suppose since `jjtable_map` and `jjtable_map_ag` (etc.) basically have the same structure: Add another column to `jjtable_map` (lets say `type`) and include that in the index `(type, picid, delete_flag, tid)`. Move all "sub-tables" with their respective types over and then use `where m.type = 'ag' and m.picid = jj.id m.delete_flag = 0 and t.tid in (98,99) and t.delete_flag = 0`. This way you would reduce database complexity and achieve better normalization. The `'_ag'` (etc.) suffixes in the table name is actually *data*, when you look at it, not structure. They ought to be *in* the table.

Comment: Regarding INDEX, I will try best configuration, thank you. For eliminating sub-table issue, I edited your answer part.

Comment: Your edit was rejected because you are not supposed to modify answers that way. I have seen it though, and you are correct: You would still keep the multiple EXISTS sub-queries, only against the same, single table now. As I said, unifying the tables is to improve the general database structure, i.e. achieve better DB-normalization.

Comment: I have got your point. I will try unifying the sub-tables and keep using EXISTS sub-queries. Thank you again for your help. EXIST subquery solution improved my program significantly.

Comment: Good to hear. Good luck with your index optimization, too. :)

Answer (score 4):

One big improvement would be to use multiple conditions at joins instead of get a huge set and then put the condition at the end. I mean, if you put the condition at the same time you join your set will be smaller and your response time better:

```
 select jj.id, jj.imgtitle, jj.alias
    from jjtable jj
    inner join jjtable_catg jjc on jj.catid = jjc.cid 
    left join jjtable_map jjtm_name on jj.id = jjtm_name.picid and jjtm_name.delete_flag = 0
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't know that I could add condition more than one on JOIN. I will try this!

Answer (score 0):

This query already have a lot of tables. Remove any table that is not used. Is there any reason for this joins?

```
left join jjtable_map_im jjtm_im on jj.id = jjtm_im.picid
left join jjtable_tags jjts_im on jjtm_im.tid = jjts_im.tid where jj.published = 1
```

jjtm_im and jjts_im  are not used at all.

Comment: Thank you. I add why need these tables on EDIT.